# jQuery: Convert to a single tag

Tags: jquery-selectors

I want to convert the below HTML to single tag: 
Before :

```
<div class="Parent1">
    <div class="Child1">
        <a href="#">Child1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="Child2">
        <a href="#">Child2</a>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="Parent2">
      <div class="Child1">
        <a href="#">Child1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="Child2">
        <a href="#">Child2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

After :

```
<div class="Parent1">
  <button>Child1</button>
  <button>Child2</button>
</div>
<div class="Parent2">
  <button>Child1</button>
  <button>Child2</button>
</div>
```

i tried with wrapping/unwrapping. But it does not work. This I want to be generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CuSdX/2/)):

```
$('div[class^="Parent"]').each(function(index, parent) {
  var html = [];
  $('a', parent).each(function(index, child) {
      html.push('<button>'+$(child).html()+'</button>');
  });
  $(parent).html(html.join(''));
});
```

It assumes that there is a pattern to the parent divs but that that isn't some common class name.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What does ^= mean in jquery?

Comment: It's a pseudo selector it means "starts with"

Comment: Cant I put $(".Parent1").ready(function({
// your code here

});

Comment: That will only match elements with the class "Parent1" in your example you have two elements with different classes. The pseudo selector will match both but not match other divs

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
$("a").unwrap().wrap("<button>").parent().text(function () { 
    return $(this).text();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/Gct7H/

Another one in the same spirit:

```
$("a").unwrap().replaceWith(function () {
    return $("<button>", {text: $(this).text()});
});
```

---

PS: In reality you would want to select something more specific than just `$("a")`. Maybe `$("#container a")` or `$("a.someClass")`, depending on your markup.